# How to properly use functions from std::algorithm with parallel execution policy in Cython?

Tags: cythonize

I'm trying to follow this guide https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-python-on-gpus-with-nvc-and-cython/

I've copied algorithm.pxd and execution.pxd from example repo https://github.com/shwina/stdpar-cython and compiling my code with MSVC compiler with /std:c++17 option;

Algorithm.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std" nogil:
    OutputIt copy[ExecutionPolicy, InputIt, OutputIt](ExecutionPolicy&& policy, InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first) except +
    void for_each[ExecutionPolicy, Iter, UnaryFunction](ExecutionPolicy&& policy, Iter first, Iter last, UnaryFunction f) except +  # actually returns f
```

Execution.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "<execution>" namespace "std::execution" nogil:
    cdef cppclass sequenced_policy:
        pass
    cdef cppclass parallel_policy:
        pass
    cdef cppclass parallel_unsequenced_policy:
        pass
    cdef cppclass unsequenced_policy:
        pass

    const sequenced_policy seq "std::execution::seq"
    const parallel_policy par "std::execution::par"
    const parallel_unsequenced_policy par_unseq "std::execution::par_unseq"
    const unsequenced_policy unseq "std::execution::unseq"
```

and making similar calls in my code:

```
from nlu.ext.algorithm cimport copy, for_each
from nlu.ext.execution cimport seq, par
....
copy(seq, &m1[0, 0], &m1[-1, -1], m1_vector.begin())
```

but they give following error during compilation:

```
error C2664: '_FwdIt2 std::copy<const std::execution::sequenced_policy,float*,std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,0>(_ExPo &&,_FwdIt1,_FwdIt1,_FwdIt2) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::execution::sequenced_policy' to '_ExPo &&'
```

And inside generated .cpp file this copy call looks this way:

```
std::copy<std::execution::sequenced_policy const ,float *,std::vector<float> ::iterator>(std::execution::seq, (&(*((float *) ( /* dim=1 */ (( /* dim=0 */ (__pyx_v_m1.data + __pyx_t_8 * __pyx_v_m1.strides[0]) ) + __pyx_t_9 * __pyx_v_m1.strides[1]) )))), (&(*((float *) ( /* dim=1 */ (( /* dim=0 */ (__pyx_v_m1.data + __pyx_t_11 * __pyx_v_m1.strides[0]) ) + __pyx_t_12 * __pyx_v_m1.strides[1]) )))), __pyx_v_m1_vector.begin());
```

As I understand, this problem arises because for some reason Cython compiler uses python class name (sequenced_policy -> std::execution::sequenced_policy) as a template parameter (which I think is wrong) and C++ class name (seq -> std::execution::seq) as an argument type.

How can this be fixed?